# Magento 2, how to hide button 'Invoice' when status 'pending'?

Tags: magento2.2, adminhtml, order-status, status

Using `magento 2.2`, `admin`, `sale->order`. I want to **hide** button **Invoice** when status **Pending**.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

`vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_view.xml` override file in your module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="sales_order_transactions_grid_block"/>
    <update handle="sales_order_item_price"/>
    <body>
         <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View" name="sales_order_edit"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

create a file `View.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order;

class View extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'order_id';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_order';
        $this->_mode = 'view';

        parent::_construct();


        $this->removeButton('delete');
        $this->removeButton('reset');
        $this->removeButton('save');
        $this->setId('sales_order_view');
        $order = $this->getOrder();

        if (!$order) {
            return;
        }

        if($order->getStatus() != 'pending'){

            if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Magento_Sales::invoice') && $order->canInvoice()) {
                $_label = $order->getForcedShipmentWithInvoice() ? __('Invoice and Ship') : __('Invoice');
                $this->addButton(
                    'order_invoice',
                    [
                        'label' => $_label,
                        'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getInvoiceUrl() . '\')',
                        'class' => 'invoice'
                    ]
                );
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

override `\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View.php` Class and add condition where invoice button created as below:

```
if($order->getStatus() != 'pending')
        {
           if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Magento_Sales::invoice') && $order->canInvoice()) {
                $_label = $order->getForcedShipmentWithInvoice() ? __('Invoice and Ship') : __('Invoice');
                $this->addButton(
                    'order_invoice',
                    [
                        'label' => $_label,
                        'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getInvoiceUrl() . '\')',
                        'class' => 'invoice'
                    ]
                );
            } 
        }
```

Check result Screenshot:
[image]